# iOS app crashes with objc_release EXC_BAD_ACCESS on startup

Tags: ios, nszombie, nszombieenabled

My app keeps (which uses ARC) crashes right after startup, with the following backtraces of the threads:

[image]

[image]

The weird thing is that when I try to run the app with Instruments-Zombie tool, the app works fine and doesn't crash, but I get no zombie accessed notification on the instrument panel. If it works fine with zombies flag enabled, I would at least expect to see one zombie notification!

Any ideas on how to further approach this issue?

## Edit

So here is some code, and I've managed to narrow the problem to a specific code path.

```
XYZStore.h/m:

@property (nonatomic,strong,readonly) NSManagedObjectContext* mainManagedObjectContext;

@implementation XYZStore

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyApp.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)mainManagedObjectContext
{
    if (_mainManagedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _mainManagedObjectContext;
    }

    _mainManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    _mainManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    return _mainManagedObjectContext;
}

Initial view controller:


-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    XYZAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc= delegate.store.mainManagedObjectContext; // managed context object from XYZStore

    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                              entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    [request setEntity:entityDescription];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    for (id *obj in results) {
        NSLog(@"%p", obj);
    }
    NSLog(@"%d", [results count]); // print "232"
}
```

This code path throws the exception I attached above (objc_release).

Two important things I've noticed:

1) If I insert `[moc reset]` after the fetch, the exception is not raised anymore (this is of course not scalable for my program, as I am dealing with NSFetchRequestControllers and such).

2) If I don't use the main object context, but a an object context in a private queue, then the exception is not raised as well.

### Full backtrace:

(lldb) thread backtrace

> - thread #1: tid = 0x9c9a, 0x03b39e85 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_release + 21, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS
>     (code=1, address=0xd0000010)   * frame #0: 0x03b39e85
>     libobjc.A.dylib`objc_release + 21
>     frame #1: 0x03b3ad32 libobjc.A.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 586
>     frame #2: 0x04153678 CoreFoundation`_CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 24
>     frame #3: 0x01123184 Foundation`-[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 149
>     frame #4: 0x0379a9ec CoreData`_performRunLoopAction + 348
>     frame #5: 0x041949de CoreFoundation`**CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION**
> - 30
>     frame #6: 0x04194920 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 400
>     frame #7: 0x0418a35a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1226
>     frame #8: 0x04189bcb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
>     frame #9: 0x041899fb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
>     frame #10: 0x05c4d24f GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 192
>     frame #11: 0x05c4d08c GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
>     frame #12: 0x01de48b6 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1526
>     frame #13: 0x000611cd Contacit`main(argc=1, argv=0xbfff83b0) + 141 at main.m:16
>     frame #14: 0x0482cac9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1

So any help in the investigation would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Try to identify code crashing with breakpoint and post here the portion of code that crash. Without code what can we do... ?

Comment: Did you try to add exception breakpoint (left window, type breakpoint tab and "plus" icon -> add exception breakpoint) ?

Comment: Hey, you guys are right. I added some code and a bit of my insights from further investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this was the cause to the problem... In my extended NSManagedObject class I had overriden this method

```
- (void)willTurnIntoFault
{
    [super willTurnIntoFault];

    if ([self observationInfo])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ has observers:\n%@", [self objectID], [self observationInfo]);
    }
}
```

Removing this fixed the issue.